# If $H(b) ≤ b$ then $\int_0^k(v−b)h(b)−[1−H(b)]db≤0 $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, auction-theory

$H$  is a CDF over $[0,1]$ and $v$ is a constant

I want to prove that if $H(b)≤b$ for all $b \in [0,1]$ then :

$$\int_0^k(v−b)h(b)−[1−H(b)]db≤0 $$
for all $k∈[0,1]$

I asked a similar question, but this is another question that I am interested in, Can anyone help me to prove this? or does any theorem helps?

Comment: I have given an answer to the other question. Do you agree with the solution? What do you think?

Comment: I've added a comment there too. Thank you!! I appreciate your help !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_0^k((v−b)h(b)−(1−H(b))=db≤0$$ iff

$$vH(k)-\int_0^kbh(b)+\int_0^kH(b)db≤\int_0^k 1db=k.$$

Now, using integration by parts, it is

$$\int_0^kbh(b)db=[bH(b)]_0^k-\int_0^kH(b)db=kH(k)-\int_0^kH(b)db.$$ Thus, the inequality is equivalent to

$$(v-k)H(k)\le k.$$ Since $H(k)\le k$ it is enough to show

$$(v-k)k\le k.$$ In other words

$$vk\le k+k^2$$ which holds because $vk\le k.$

Comment: Thank you. At the first "iff", where did -1 go ?

Comment: It was a mistake. I think it was fixed.

Comment: Thank you for helping me. One mistake I noticed is that $\int_0^k  bh(b)db=[bH(b)]_0^k− \int_0^k h(b) db $ This should be $\int_0^k  bh(b)db=[bH(b)]_0^k−\int_0^k H(b) db $ . But this gives me a new approach.

Comment: I fixed the mistake. At least I hope.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is flawless. I accepted the answer. $(v−k)k≤k$ part is enough for my original intention of the question. I can get this from here: when $v-k \leq 1$, this inequality holds

Comment: You don't need to assume $v-k\le 1.$ Note that $$vk\le k\le k+k^2\implies  vk\le k +k^2 \iff (v-k)k\le k.$$

Comment: So only need $v \leq 1$. That is great!!!